# Oracle: named subquery in having clause

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

How do I refer to the *network* column from the subselect in the **having** clause?

```
select distinct c.id, c.name,
(
select count(cm.id) cnt
from
company_mapping cm
where
cm.company_id_source = c.id
or
cm.company_id_target = c.id
) network
from company c
where
c.name like 'foobar%'
group by c.id, c.name
having network > 1
```

ORA-00904: "NETWORK": invalid identifier. If I leave out the last line, it works as expected but I'm only interested in rows having network > 1.

Comment: Have you tried changing `network` to something else, for example `aaaaa`

Comment: "AAA": invalid identifier - gives the same error code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>First, you can't have `distinct` and `group by` in the same query.</strike> It's only redundant, you are right, I don't know why oracle doesn't throw an exception.

Second, the alias is not known at the same level as the query. You should enclose this in outer query.

```
select id, name, network
from (
    select c.id, c.name,
      (
      select count(cm.id) cnt
      from
      company_mapping cm
      where
      cm.company_id_source = c.id
      or
      cm.company_id_target = c.id
      ) network
    from company c
    where
    c.name like 'foobar%'
    group by c.id, c.name
)
WHERE network > 1;
```

Comment: You mean the _distinct_ is redundant? Because Oracle doesn't complain about using both _distinct_ and _group by_ in my example.

Comment: If c.id is the primary key on the company table then the group by is redundant -- if it is not then you'd do better to define an in-line view to return distinct c.id and c.name prior to applying the subquery in the select. Come to think of it, you might as well get rid of the subquery and just join from company to company_mapping, using a having clause to filter the aggregate result.

Answer (score 9):

You can't access field which is defined in `select` in `group by`, `having` or  `where`.

The order of sql operators is as follows :

```
1.FROM clause
2.WHERE clause
3.GROUP BY clause
4.HAVING clause
5.SELECT clause
6.ORDER BY clause
```

That's why you can use `network` in `order by` but not in operators which come before `select`.

Comment: +1 nice answer! (and if you put a link to docs would be even nicer :))

Comment: You can see the order of MSSQL here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx. I believe that Oracle's logical order is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
select c.id
      ,c.name
      ,count(*) 
      ,count(s.company_id_source) as num_sources
      ,count(t.company_id_target) as num_targets
  from company              c
  left join company_mapping s on(s.company_id_source = c.id)
  left join company_mapping t on(t.company_id_target = c.id)
 where c.name like 'foobar%'  
 group 
    by c.id
      ,c.name
having count(s.company_id_source) > 1
    or count(t.company_id_target) > 1;
```

**Edit**:
New query below in response to comments.
The query is now returning: All companies matching "Foobar" regardless of whether they have an associated row in table company_mapping, along with:

- num_sources: The nr of rows in company_mapping where the company is
  the source.
- num_targets: The nr of rows in company_mapping where the
  company is the target.
- num_mappings: The nr of "connections" in company_mapping (either source or target)

.

```
select c.id
      ,c.name
      ,count(s.company_id_source) + count(t.company_id_target)   as num_mappings
      ,count(s.company_id_source) as num_sources
      ,count(t.company_id_target) as num_targets
  from company              c
  left join company_mapping s on(s.company_id_source = c.id)
  left join company_mapping t on(t.company_id_target = c.id)
 where c.name like 'foobar%'  
 group 
    by c.id
      ,c.name;
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I was thinking, but I'd use a single company_mapping table and put both join conditions in that if possible. I think the left join could then be an inner join also.

Comment: Yes, I already tried having two left joins but I definitely need the count of both in a single column.

Comment: @kosmičák, you get the count with COUNT(*). Since I'm outer joining to company_mapping twice, you can easily get the individal count for source/target as well.

Comment: @DavidAldridge, Good point! I didn't think of combining them into one until I saw Bazz's solution. But I think I'm leaving it this way just to provide an alternative solution. The execution plans will be different between his solution and mine.

Comment: @Ronnies still, companies without an associated row in company_mapping have count(*)=1 instead of 0, that's wrong

Comment: @kosmičák, ouch! Fixing it, wait :)

Comment: Just tested the performance, it's fast... under 2s on our data, it would be great if someone figured out what's the problem with Bazz's solution.

Comment: If you forget about the having clause (the limit of > 1 was just an example), how to get 0 in the 3rd column for companies that have no associated row in company_mapping?

Comment: I think I got it, this is the select clause that works: select c.id, c.name, count(s.company_id_source) + count(t.company_id_target) ...

Comment: @kosmičák, If you remove the having clause entirely, you would get all company rows (matching foobar) regardless if they have an associated row in  company_mapping. Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. You can also add count(s.company_id_source) + count(t.company_id_target), or even count(coalesce(s.company_id_source, t.company_id_target))

Comment: Yes, we need to see all of them with the number of associated rows, 0 if there are none.

Comment: @Ronnis, it's exactly what I needed and the discussion with you helped me most but I can't make it the accepted answer because my original question was only about the having clause and those who come here later might be confused.

Answer (score 3):

Ronnis is on the right path, but the query should actually be even simpler.
Please try to avoid select inside select, because it is a performance killer 99% of the time.

```
select c.id
,      c.name
,      count(*) network
from   company c
join   company_mapping cm on c.id in (cm.company_id_source, cm.company_id_target)
where  c.name like 'foobar%'
group by c.id, c.name
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Something is weird here... I removed the having clause and run both my initial version and yours, replaced foobar with something meaningful and on our database your query takes between 30-40s, mine less than 2 seconds. Also your version doesn't return companies where network=0.

Comment: Could the difference be that your version has to create a huge cartesian product first and only then pick those with name like 'foobar%' while in mine it first picks those foobar rows and only apply the subselect for them?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I use join and not left join, because of the rule that count(*) had to be greater than 1. Use left join if you want network = 0 in the list too. I guess the reason for the bad performance is that Oracle doesn't use indexes with this IN join. Either add an index on company_id_source & company_id_target (together) or change the query to use an index.